# Get Page Source As Browser Shows In Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape some data as seen in my browser.
Here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
print(lol.page_source)
```

With this I essentially get a bunch of javascript but what I really want is an HTMLesque code. I know webbot can achieve this through experiments on my old PC, but webbot only supports chrome which I don't want to install (for reasons that are mainly about design). Is there anyway to do this with selenium?

Coming across some research Ajax elements might prevent this.

Comment: did you try to `sleep()` so JavaScript will have time to add elements to HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS_SELECTOR to wrap the "body" tag.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

html = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body").text
print(html)
```

EDIT1: If you want the header, you can just substitute `"body"` with `"header"`.

EDIT2: You can also use the universal CSS selector `"*"`.

EDIT3: If you want plain HTML, it can be done using `requests` library:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')

r = requests.get(driver.current_url)
html = r.content
print(html)
```